# Couchbase 4.0 Community Edition benchmark

Tags: couchbase, ycsb

We are benchmarking couchbase and observing a very strange behaviour.

## **Setup phase:**

### **Couchbase cluster machines;**

2 x EC2 r3.xlarge with General purpose 80GB SSD (Not EBS optimised ) , IOPS 240/3000.

#### Couchbase settings:

Cluster: 
Data Ram Quota: 22407 MB
Index Ram Quota: 2024 MB
Index Settings (default)
Bucket:
Per Node Ram Quota: 22407 MB
Total Bucket Size: 44814 MB (22407 x 2)
Replicas enabled (1)
Disk I/O Optimisation (Low)

Each node runs all three services

### **Couchbase client;**

1 x EC2 m4.xlarge General purpose 20 GB SSD (EBS Optimised), IOPS 60/3000.
The client is running the 'YCSB' benchmark tool.

*ycsb load couchbase -s -P workloads/workloada -p recordcount=100000000 -p core_workload_insertion_retry_limit=3 -p couchbase.url=http://HOST:8091/pools -p couchbase.bucket=test -threads 20 | tee workloadaLoad.dat*

PS: All the machines are residing within the same VPC and subnet.

## **Results:**

**While everything works as expected**
The average ops/sec is ~21000
The 'disk write queue' graph is floating between 200K - 600K(periodically drained).
The 'temp OOM per sec' graph is at constant 0.

**When things starting to get weird**
After about ~27M documents inserted we start seeing 'disk write queue' is constantly rising (Not getting drained)
At about ~8M disk queue size the OOM failures are starting to show them selves and the client receives 'Temporary failure' from couchbase.
After 3 retries of each YCSB thread, the client stops after inserting only ~27% of the overall documents.
Even when the YCSB client stopped running, the 'disk write queue' is asymptotically moving towards 0, and is drained only after ~15 min.

P.S 
When we benchmark locally on MacBook with 16GB of ram + SSD disk (local client + one node server) we do not observe such behaviour and the 'disk write queue' is constantly drained in a predictable manner.

Thanks.

Comment: Which version of YCSB are you using and where did you get it? I ask as there are some strange versions floating around. I am not saying it is the problem, I just want more color.

Comment: Hi.. Just pulled the 'master' and built the HEAD.

Comment: It doesn't seem like client issue since we're definitely observing strange behaviour on the couchbase side - the 'disk write queue' at some point in time is just rising and rising. The question is what could be the cause of it?

Comment: Could you post the result of `iostat -mx 5` during this 27M+ period please? The 2nd block of results, first one is the total since server boot.

Comment: I will run the benchmark again and then update you with iostat as you requested.

Comment: [Here](http://www.filedropper.com/diskstat) are the disk statistics from one of the 'couchbase' nodes